# cocoa app: Checking if certain programs are installed

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am creating an application for mac and that application requires two programs to be installed on the mac before it functions correctly so I need some way to check if the programs are installed.
These are the ones:

- system_timer
- shenzhen

I have already installed them on my mac with:

```
sudo gem install system_timer
sudo gem install shenzhen
```

in the terminal.

The app is to be distributed internally and I can't ask everyone to install these two programs on their machines so I need my application to do that automatically if they are not installed.

How would I go about doing that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [popen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/popen/) to run the shell commands `which system_timer` and `which shenzhen` and then check the results.

Comment: `popen("which system_timer", "r")` returns a file which I have no idea how to handle, is it the correct way?

Comment: popen returns a file handle to stdout of the command executed. Call `which system_timer` from a console on a system where it is installed and where it is not and see the difference in the output.

Comment: I tried the command in the terminal and nothing happens, it just goes to next line like nothing happened.

Comment: If you type `which system_timer` at a shell prompt you should get the path to `system_timer`, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/system_timer` (or wherever it happens to be installed). This assumes you actually have it installed of course, and that your `PATH` is correctly set up (otherwise you will get no output from `which`). Assuming that works OK then you can do the same thing from within your program, using `popen`.

Comment: FWIW, (not that it will solve any `PATH` issues, but...) you might have an easier time of this using `NSTask` instead of `popen` for this.

Comment: @ipmcc: you're probably right - I was going for a more generic and portable solution but if this is only ever going to be needed on OS X then perhaps `NSTask` would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your advices I am working on a solution will update when I get it working

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, you would want to find a way to package the necessary resources in your app bundle, rather than requiring your users to give your app root privileges to have the `gem` package manager install the packages globally. Sadly, `system_timer` has native build requirements, and `shenzhen` has a bunch of dependencies, so this might not be as easy as it could be.

Assuming you just want to do the equivalent of `sudo gem install ...` I would recommend executing `gem` with elevated privileges using something like the code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) (be sure to check out the README file there -- this is not a one-liner) to invoke it with root privileges. This will use the current, recommended privilege elevation API and will present the user with the normal dialog box to enter their password.